# A usage of "refer to"

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

> This passage is a much fuller account of the coming of the Elves
>   Gelmir and Arminas to Nargothrond in the year of its fall (The
>   Silmarillion pp. 211-12); for their earlier encounter with Tuor in
>   Dor-lómin, **which is referred to here**, see pp. 23-24 above.

This is some of the editor's comment from *Unfinished Tales* by J.R.R. Tolkien

I couldn't find relevant definition when I referred to the dictionary.
If it were *which refers the readers to here*, it feels make sense.
Could you explain or give me some example of this usage, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*is referred to* is a passive construction, whose subject, *which*, has *their earlier encounter...* as its referent. That encounter is *referred to here*—that is, mentioned in the passage which he is currently discussing:

> And in the wastes of Dor-lómin I met with Tuor son of Huor, Húrin's brother ... (p. 169)

The reader is invited to consult pp. 23-24 of the current edition for a fuller account of that encounter.

Comment: Agreed.  Does it help to explain this is the passive voice?  This passage refers to their earlier encounter, so their earlier encounter *is referred to*.

Comment: @stangdon Good point. Effected.

Comment: I see now. 'here' means the passage not the comment itself. Thanks a lot!